# Java websocket draft refuses handshake

Tags: java, android, java-websocket

I am working on android(Java) using [TooTallNate's java websockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) from [this tutorial](https://www.varvet.com/blog/using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps/) to consume websockets on android to connect with `ws://` but I am getting error `draft org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_10@4560b1d0 refuses handshake`. I tried their other draft versions but none of them worked either.

Comment: Were you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: end of 2017 and I am still facing this

Comment: Found a solution. Add /websocket at the end of your endpoint. When you use ShockJs, it adds that extra string to your endpoint. So without that you are hitting wrong endpoint which is valid only for browser based app ( expected http 200 instead of 101)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to use the `Draft_6455`, it is the current spec, the rest may or may not work on different servers reliably. There are constructors for the draft object which take a `List<IProtocol>`. If no protocol specified matches one offered by the server, the handshake will be refused.

```
public Draft_6455( List<IExtension> inputExtensions , List<IProtocol> inputProtocols )
public Draft_6455( List<IExtension> inputExtensions , List<IProtocol> inputProtocols, int inputMaxFrameSize )
```

I ran into a similar issue to yours with the newest version of TooTallNate's Java Websockets, my code was like so:

```
   knownExtensions = new java.util.ArrayList();
   knownProtocols = new java.util.ArrayList();
    if(this._protocol){
       knownProtocols.add(new org.java_websocket.protocols.Protocol(this._protocol));
    }

    this._socket = new _WebSocket(uri, new org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_6455(knownExtensions, knownProtocols), toHashMap(this._headers), this._timeout);
```

You **MUST** have at least one valid protocol (even if it is a empty string), or you get the above error you referenced.   So I changed my code to be:

```
...   
if(this._protocol){
   knownProtocols.add(new org.java_websocket.protocols.Protocol(this._protocol));
} 
/* -=-=-=- NEW ADDED CODE -=-=-=- */
else {
    knownProtocols.add(new org.java_websocket.protocols.Protocol(""));
}
/* -=-=-=- END NEW ADDED CODE -=-=-=- */
...
```

This is what broke, no protocol specified caused the "refuses handshake" error message for me.

Please note there are a couple of reasons for the above "refuses handshake", but in my case it was the missing empty protocol...

Comment: I do not understand where this code is. What type is "this"?

Comment: I was passing in a protocol to my wrapper around the library.   If a protocol wasn't set; then I then defaulted to ""

Comment: I submitted an edit to your answer for peer review. I hope you like it. I think it could help users such as myself who have a slightly different situation (I needed to specify a non-empty protocol, but essentially it is the same underlying issue). It may also focus the answer, pointing users at the problematic API surface rather than your particular code. Feel free to edit my edit if it needs some additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on broswer? You will get a err code on the broswer.

You can write a simple js file to start and test whether this problem is on the server or is on the app.

Here is a demo,it won't take you too much time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send() {
    var url = 'ws://192.168.1.101:8080/WebSocket/echo';
    var vs  = new WebSocket(url);
    vs.onopen = function(evt){
        vs.send(te.value)
    };
    vs.onmessage = function(evt){
        alert(evt.data);
    };
}
```

Comment: The server already has a perfectly working browser/website version so I'm assuming the server is fine, I am making a native android copy of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you have for example a protocol "my-protocol"

```java
ArrayList<IProtocol> protocols = new ArrayList<IProtocol>();
protocols.add(new Protocol("my-protocol"));

//Uncomment below if you want to have a fallback
//protocols.add(new Protocol(""));
Draft_6455 my_draft = new Draft_6455(Collections.<IExtension>emptyList(), protocols);
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki/Specifing-a-Sec-WebSocket-Protocol)